# Create a plane in Babylon.js with 3 Vectors

Tags: javascript, 3d, babylonjs

If I have 3 coordinates, how do I create a plane in Babylon.js with this 3 Vectors as corners?

I know I can create a plane like this:

`var plane = BABYLON.Mesh.CreatePlane("plane", 500.0, scene);`

and there is a function like

`var plane1 = BABYLON.Plane.FromPoints(new BABYLON.Vector3(0,0,0), new BABYLON.Vector3(0,50,0), new BABYLON.Vector3(0,0,50));`

But how do I get plane1 into the scene?

Answer (score 1):

the plane is just a math structure and not a mesh. The best idea could be to create a plane with CreatePlane and then scale it and move it with mesh.position and mesh.scaling

Comment: So I have to do some manual vector calculations first to get the right rotation and scaling?

If having (as an example) the Vectors (1,2,3), (5,4,8), (10,15,-10) - How would I find out from these information where to position my plane (so have to find the midpoint of the plane, right?) and the right rotation?

Answer (score 1):

Just give it some position or rotation to view perfect. I mean You must tried these

```
var plane = BABYLON.Mesh.CreatePlane("plane", 350, scene);
plane.position.y = -5;
plane.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
```

you should at-least apply some rotation on plane. like i written in code.

May it works..!